# What does #document mean? And how can I select elements outside of that code?

Tags: html, css

What does #document mean?

I have a webpage built by a tool kit. There is a widget whit that I can embed own code. But it is encapsulated as an extra #document within the general html code of the page. I would like to overwrite the css of the general webpage, maybe using this embed code widget. How can I get elements (parents) outside of this extra #document? Thanks a lot for any help!

Miminal example:

```
 <html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div class="title">Hello</div>
    ...
    #document
      <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
          i would like to inject anything here to change the color of the title
        </body>
      </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not have the code here. It might was encapsulated as an iframe but I'm not sure. I can't access the code at the moment but I added a minimal code example.

Comment: I just found out I could insert the following script, but is there a better way to really write css?

<script>document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].style.color = 'red';</script>

Comment: Oh, the `#document` means that the document is in an iframe. Sadly, you can't edit the parent page through an iframe.